# How to continue where I left off on reaver?

Tags: linux, wifi, kali-linux, wpa2, wps

I was attempting to brute-force the WPS PIN on my home router to check the security of my network. Strangely, after three days it still had not finished, I believe this is because my computer was far away from the router while I was performing this attack and set a high wait before each retry.

**Command I used:**

> reaver -i wlan0mon -b BSSID -d 30 -S -N -vv

I stupidly restarted computer, this wasted three days worth of work because I was using a live USB for Kali, I did **not** have persistent storage.

Luckily, I wrote the last count and PIN before shutting down:

> Count: 5047 (out of 11000 I think)
>
> Current PIN it was trying: 50425679

Is it possible to resume where I left off using information above? How would I write the command?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You require the `reaver` session file for this. I'm assuming you are working on a Linux system (Kali probably), the session file is saved in `/usr/local/etc/reaver` and named `<BSSID>.wpc`. Look for the session file to see if it is there. It allows reaver to resume an attack.

If the session file is missing, you can create one manually based on the information you have. In general, WPS PIN attack works in two parts: the first half -- 4 digits, 10,000 combinations -- and the second half -- 3 digits, 1000 combinations. The last digit is simply a checksum and is ignored during brute force. `reaver` is first trying to bruteforce the first digits. Did that succeed in your case? If it did, then you already know the first half of the PIN.

This session file contains 11,000 keys in two halves:

```
4 Digits (up to 9998, one on each line)
3 Digits (up to 998, one on each line)
```

Attack the station again and then quit `reaver` and open the session file. You need to modify this file such that reaver knows where it left off. Change the first pin on the first line to `50425679` in your case. The next two lines might read `0` and rest are combinations. Save the file and start reaver again. It should now pick up where it left off.

Also see:

- https://github.com/shift/reaver-wps/issues/233
- https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?18629-Possible-to-start-reaver-with-a-specific-number

Comment: Upate : On Kali 2019.1 /var/lib/reaver/